# Changing the highlight and title color for fragments in PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, android-theme

I'm using the Material theme, and I'd like to change the color of the two marked areas in the image below - i.e. the highlight color (#1) and the color of the title in the details fragment (#2).

I know there's an attribute for the color of each somewhere in the theme, but I just can't seem to find it.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> I know there's an attribute for the color of each somewhere in the
>   theme, but I just can't seem to find it.

### Item number 1

The attribute you'll want is [`activatedBackgroundIndicator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#activatedBackgroundIndicator).

**As per the docs**

> Drawable used as a background for activated items.

**Reason being**

The layout used for each header item in a `PreferenceActivity` is [`preference_header_item_material`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/preference_header_item_material.xml#L22) which uses the `activatedBackgroundIndicator` as a background. You'll need a selector for this attribute, something like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_activated="true"><color android:color="yourColor" />
    </item>
    <item><color android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </item>

</selector>
```

### Item number 2

This item is slightly trickier. It's not a `PreferenceScreen` like you suggested in the other answer, but the [`FragmentBreadCrumbs`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/FragmentBreadCrumbs.java) title. Unfortunately, the title color cannot be set using a theme because the attribute used to style it is private internal.

You can however set the text color using Reflection or just by traversing the breadcrumb's view hierarchy until you find the `TextView` used to display the title.

The layout used to display the content in each `PreferenceActivity` is [`preference_list_content_material`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/preference_list_content_material.xml#L73) which includes the [`breadcrumbs_in_fragment_material`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout-xlarge/breadcrumbs_in_fragment_material.xml) layout to display each breadcrumb. You can see from that layout that the id of each `FragmentBreadCrums` is `android:id/title`. Now we can use this id to find the breadcrumb and adjust the the `TextView` inside it.

**Using Reflection**

```
@Override
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    super.onBuildHeaders(target);
    loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.yourPreferenceHeaders, target);

    final View breadcrumb = findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    if (breadcrumb == null) {
        // Single pane layout
        return;
    }

    try {
        final Field titleColor = breadcrumb.getClass().getDeclaredField("mTextColor");
        titleColor.setAccessible(true);
        titleColor.setInt(breadcrumb, yourTitleColor);
    } catch (final Exception ignored) {
        // Nothing to do
    }

}
```

**Traversing the view hierarchy**

Using [`View.findViewsWithText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewsWithText(java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.view.View%3E,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int)) is an easy way to handle this.

```
    breadcrumb.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            breadcrumb.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

            final ArrayList<View> outViews = Lists.newArrayList();
            breadcrumb.findViewsWithText(outViews, getString(R.string.your_header_title),
                    View.FIND_VIEWS_WITH_TEXT);

            ((TextView) outViews.get(0)).setTextColor(yourTitleColor);
        }

    });
```

### Results

[image: results]

Comment: All right, I've tested both solutions for the second part of the answer, and just thought I'd add a few notes. Reflection is by far the easiest and most reliant way of doing it - it feels hacky, though. I would've prefered using the view hierachy, but it quickly gets complicated because it needs the title of the breadcrumb, and it also resets the text color change when you switch between the preference categories. You'll need to override onDestroy in the PreferenceActivity and remove the layout listener there instead of in the method itself.

Comment: Great solution! The only problem (with using reflection), is that when the user switch from landscape to portrait, or vice versa, title returns to black. My dirty fix was that I thought it has something to do with "caching fragment state", or something like that, and so I ended up detecting that if we just came from an orientation change, I'm restarting the settings activity by calling finish() and startActivity(). It's dirty but it's invisible to the user and it works. If someone got a better solution...

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the suggested solution, now it works perfectly also for screen rotations.

In the base `Activity` class for our preferences we have to do the following:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    if ("android.app.FragmentBreadCrumbs".equals(name))
    {
        final View title = new android.app.FragmentBreadCrumbs(context, attrs);
        try {
            final Field titleColor = title.getClass().getDeclaredField("mTextColor");
            titleColor.setAccessible(true);
            titleColor.setInt(title, title_color));
        } catch (final Exception ignored) {
            // Nothing to do
        }
        return title;
    }
    return super.onCreateView(name, context, attrs);
}
```

and that's it.